# Ninject to load different implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have a web service (let's call it `WebSite`) that uses an Interface (`IDataService`). the webservice project implements a "fake" service with hardcoded objects (`DesignDataService`) that I use to develop the websit while I wait for my colleagues to build the real implementation (`BreadDataService`).

My NinjectWebCommon is currently like this:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
  kernel.Bind<IDataService>().To<DesignDataService>();
}
```

What I want is to be able to provide my colleague a way to test the `BreadDataService` on my WebService, while I can go on using `DesignDataService`. I can't use the `BreadDataService` on my machine because it requires some assemblies that I don't have (+ the database).

So, what is the approach here? The current dependency tree is like that:

- `ServiceCore` (defines `IDataService`)
- `WebSite` uses `ServiceCore`
- `BreadDataService` uses `ServiceCore`

I don't want to reference the `BreadDataService` project inside the `WebSite` Project, I was maybe thinking about a folder in `WebSite` where they can put the `BreadDataService` dll and ninject takes it depending on some configuration in web.config.

Hints?

Comment: Is the BreadDataService.dll always in the `WebSite` folder - and you need to configure it in the `web.config` or is it also ok to "configure" it by putting the dll into the `WebSite` folder and removing it? Do you know how to configure ninject to load Modules of other assemblies or do you need help on that, too?

Comment: First question: either approach is acceptable
Second question: The fact that I am not sure how to answer let me think I don't know :D As I showed, my Ninject configuration is very basic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used qujck approach to build these [extension methods](https://gist.github.com/itajaja/7936033).
The main difference is that it relies on `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions`' `FromAssembliesInPath` method

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do the trick

- load external assemblies
- search for an implementation
- default to your design time version if none are found

Here's the basic code

```
IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = this.LoadAssemblies(@"C:\Temp");
Type implementation = FindImplementation(assemblies, typeof(IDataService));

IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind<IDataService>().To(implementation ?? typeof(DesignDataService));
```

This method will load external assemblies (such as plugins) from a specific folder

```
private IEnumerable<Assembly> LoadAssemblies(string folder)
{
    IEnumerable<string> dlls =
        from file in new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles()
        where file.Extension == ".dll"
        select file.FullName;

    IList<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

    foreach (string dll in dlls)
    {
        try
        {
            assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    return assemblies;
}
```

And this method will search a set of assemblies for an implementation. Please note that I have specifically used `SingleOrDefault()` so that this will fail if there is more than one implementation.

```
private Type FindImplementation(
    IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies, 
    Type serviceType)
{
    var implementationType = (
        from dll in assemblies
        from type in dll.GetExportedTypes()
        where serviceType.IsAssignableFrom(type)
        where !type.IsAbstract
        where !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition
        select type)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    return implementationType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your answer as an inspiration for my solution!